# x-Axis tick alignment

Tags: highcharts, alignment

I have a problem with Highcharts, when trying to position the `x-Axis` tick marks according to the column data shown. I want to align the x-axis ticks on the right, but all the time they are displayed on the center. `X-axis` must be numbers, so I don't have categories.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mabaes/Qap8Q/)

Comment: So ticks should be between columns ?

Answer (score 5):

Experiment with the [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointPlacement) option.

For instance:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPlacement: -0.5
    }
}
```

Produces (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qap8Q/2/)):

[image]